# How to join two tables of two different queries in sql?

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables which are the output of two different queries, how can i join those two tables.
following are the queries used :

```
SELECT layerrate, tpnativename, directionality  
FROM topologicallink 
  JOIN tp ON topologicallink.aendtp=tp.tpid 
         AND topologicallink.aendne='44' ;

SELECT tpnativename 
from topologicallink 
  JOIN tp ON topologicallink.zendtp=tp.tpid 
         AND topologicallink.zendne='44';
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: contents of both tables in a single table...

Comment: What you are trying to do is really unclear. Plus: what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I don't see why you would even need the second one. It returns the same rows as the first, only with fewer columns. The first one includes everything the second one has.

Comment: why don't you combine the select clauses?

Comment: The second query gives a different result, as topologicallink.zendtp=tp.tpid(second query) and topologicallink.aendtp=tp.tpid(first query)are not same

Answer (score 1):

Take use of the `UNION` keyword

```
SELECT layerrate, tpnativename, directionality  
FROM topologicallink 
  JOIN tp ON topologicallink.aendtp=tp.tpid 
         AND topologicallink.aendne='44' ;
UNION

SELECT tpnativename, '',''
from topologicallink 
  JOIN tp ON topologicallink.zendtp=tp.tpid 
         AND topologicallink.zendne='44';
```

In the second query you see two times `''`. This is needed because you have to have the equal amount of columns for each query if you want to use `UNION`

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use UNION ALL:

```
SELECT layerrate, tpnativename, directionality  
FROM topologicallink 
  JOIN tp ON topologicallink.aendtp=tp.tpid 
         AND topologicallink.aendne='44' 
UNION ALL
SELECT null, tpnativename, null
from topologicallink 
  JOIN tp ON topologicallink.zendtp=tp.tpid 
         AND topologicallink.zendne='44';
```

Comment: HI, I have tried UNION All before,but this appends the result to same column. what i was trying is to append the result of second query to a new COLUMN.

Comment: But these are different selects. How are they related? Say first query gives you two records 1-A-5 and 2-B-6, and second statement gives you two records B and D. What result do you want to see? All four combinations 1-A-5-B, 1-A-5-D, 2-B-6-B, and 2-B-6-D? Or only some of them? Or something entirely else?

Comment: 1-A-5,2-B-6 in one column and B,D in another column

Comment: Ah, you only want to get one record back, with strings concatenated. There is no standard SQL solution for that. Oracle uses LISTAGG, MySQL uses GROUP_CONCAT, etc. Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT layerrate, tpnativename, directionality  
FROM topologicallink 
  JOIN tp ON topologicallink.aendtp=tp.tpid 
         AND topologicallink.aendne='44'

UNION

SELECT layerrate, tpnativename, directionality  
from topologicallink 
  JOIN tp ON topologicallink.zendtp=tp.tpid 
         AND topologicallink.zendne='44';
```